# What's the meaning of "floss" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, slang

This short dialogue is from the movie Nick and Norah's Infinite Playlist:

> Nick: Do you guys talk a lot? Talk about her (Tris) new boyfriend?
>
> Norah: I cannot believe Tris dated a straightedge. That's, like, astounding.
>
> Nick: What did she say about me? She said I was a straightedge?
>
> Norah: Can I ask, what did you see in her? I could **floss with** that girl.
>
> Nick: This is your friend that we are talking about?
>
> Norah: All right. I'm the bad guy now. Is this what we're doing? I'm the bad guy?

Background: Norah is into Nick, but Nick is hung up on his ex-girlfriend Tris. So here when Nick brings up Tris, Norah is apparently miffed.

Having checked Urban Dictionary, I haven't found a definition that fits the context. Urban Dictionary mentions "show off" but it doesn't seem relevant. From what Nick says after that line, it seems Norah's words are not very flattering. What does it mean here?

Comment: @Andrew I have just updated the question to include a bit more information. I was hesitant to put up more of the dialogue because what precedes and follows is tangential. In the film Norah finds Nick keeping talking about Tris very annoying. So I don't think she considers Tris attractive.

Comment: Yep, my previous comment was way off-target.

Answer (score 2):

I did end up watching the scene in question (about 29 minutes into the movie on [Netflix](https://www.netflix.com/title/70104311)).  Here *floss" implies the girl in question is excessively *shallow* (she is only concerned with herself, or silly and inconsequential things) so much so that that she could (metaphorically) slide between Norah's teeth, like a piece of [*dental floss*](https://azcdn.cassini.pgsitecore.com/en-us/-/media/OralB/Images/Editorials/ArticleDetail/DT/Archive/history-dental-floss.jpg?la=en-US&v=1-201706291408).

It's clear Norah doesn't think much of Tris, even though they are friends.

Comment: Thanks for going the extra mile to write an answer!